# HV9961 led driver: trying 170V led output

Tags: led, driver

I face to some issue with my prototype based on the HV9961 (see picture).[image]

I replaced L1 by a 1.8mH power inductor and R1 by a 68k resistor. Those values came from HV9961 datasheet formulas for a 170V led output. Also i added a potentiometer between R2 and the LD pin to adjust the VLD voltage between 0.2V and 1.6V. The output led current depends of the VLD voltage. R6 and R6a have been replaced by a 0.3 Ohm to setup ILED at 920mA max.

After power on, my design works very well. The 170V led string sees a 350mA when VLD is adjusted at 0.6V and brights fine. But after 5-10mn, D1 breaks! I decided to change D1 by the same reference STTH2R06H (fast recovery diode 600V 2A). The problem is the same, D1 is destroyed after 5 min.

Could you help me to find the good recovery diode ? and explain why it breaks ?
|

---

[HV9961 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005588A.pdf)
[STD5NM50 datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/ST%20Microelectronics%20PDFS/STD5NM50(-1).pdf)
[STTH2R06 datasheet](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/fe/4e/e1/d9/af/18/4b/81/CD00043011.pdf/files/CD00043011.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00043011.pdf)

Comment: Where possible PLESSe provide datasheets eg [STTH2R06U datasheet](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/fe/4e/e1/d9/af/18/4b/81/CD00043011.pdf/files/CD00043011.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00043011.pdf) || What is the diode package? How is it heatsunk? How hot does it get? What is its FORWARD voltage . What is its reverse voltage? || V

Comment: Reverse voltage should be only about 330 VDC. Dissipation steady state should be maybe slightly over 0.5 Watt. (Fig1 page 3, 0.4A, ~~~= 50% on. | I'd not expect dI/dT to be an issue. Maybe recovery losses but ...? || Try a say 10 Ohm resistor n series with D1 - it drops about 3V in operation (so minimal loss %) but may soften the Q1 turnoff. Maybe a small cap across D1. Small. . || [HV9961 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005588A.pdf)

Comment: Thanks you Russell, i will try all of this. But i still don't understand why this diode failure happens.
If someone could share his knowledge too. ;)

Comment: Can i add 2, 3 or 4 diodes in parallel to limit each one's power ?

Comment: We don't know either - but, as you say you are using components and design parameters from the data sheet, then your answering the questions that I asked may be a major factor in solving your problems, or not. No amount of our "sharing our knowledge" will help if you have used a high thermal resistance pkg device, heatinking is minimal and it is filing due to overtemperature. Until you answer the related questions so we know what you know then endless speculation on our part is pointless. What are the answers to the questions above. If you don't know you need to.

Comment: re "Can i add 2, 3 or 4 diodes in parallel to limit each one's power ?" -> you can do random things to try to fix what you hope may be wrong, but investigating systematically is liable to be more useful. Multiple diodes may work but may not. You haven't told us okg, temperature, ... yet so we do not know if power may be an issue. The more you cn tell us about what you are doing and seeing the better.

Comment: sorry for delay, i used SMB package for the diode STTH2R06U. Specifiactions: Repetitive peak reverse voltage 600V / Forward rms current 7A / Average forward current δ = 0.5 (SMB) 2A / Forward voltage drop (125°C) 1.25V. The diode temperature increases very quickly when the design is powered and it becomes very hot before crashing. According to me, diode voltage and current specifications seem matching with the design, so i don't understand this diode behavior.

Comment: Could STPSC4H065 match with [STPSC4H065 datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/stpsc4h065-956663.pdf) ?

Comment: I am now uncertain as to what diode you are using. Specs I wanted were as measured in your cct.| You have not said what heatsink you are using or how hot "very hot" is. SMB Rth-jc  is 25C/Watt so you should have no problems IF the diode has adequate heat sinking. BUT fig 11 in [datasheet](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/fe/4e/e1/d9/af/18/4b/81/CD00043011.pdf/files/CD00043011.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00043011.pdf) shows Rth-ja of 90 C/W - without any heatsinking you are liable to "have problems" if air access is other than superb. ...

Comment: 3 cm^2 FR4 PCB copper gives about 60 C/W.

Comment: Thanks Russell for these details about temperature. I cannot measure temperature and there is no heatsink for my SMB package. But here I need a quick course about "Thermal resistance junction to ambient versus copper surface under each lead". Sorry but I'm novice so please could you explain what does it mean, in simple words ;)

Comment: If you burn yourself on it you probably need more heat sink. It WILL run far hotter than that but ... . JUST able to keep touching is about 55 C. If a drop of water on it boils or if when you lick your finger and dab at it with the wetted finger it hisses it's over 100 degrees C. Even that's perhaps OK but also maybe not. 
If it DOESN'T ever get hiss test hot it's probably OK. j=junction, c=case, a=air. Rth = thermal resistance. Rth_jc is Rth from junction to case. Rth_ca = case to air. With no heatsing Rthca = 90 C/W. ie junction is 90C > air temp with no heatsink. Rthjc is 25 C/W...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I said:

What is the diode package?
How is it heatsunk?
How hot does it get?
What is its FORWARD voltage .

Reverse voltage should be only about 330 VDC.
Dissipation steady state should be maybe slightly over 0.5 Watt. (Fig1 page 3, 0.4A, ~~~= 50% on.
I'd not expect dI/dT to be an issue.
Maybe recovery losses but ...?
Try a say 10 Ohm resistor n series with D1 - it drops about 3V in operation (so minimal loss %) but may soften the Q1 turnoff. Maybe a small cap across D1. Small.

If you have used a high thermal resistance pkg device, heatinking is minimal and it is filing due to overtemperature.

> You said: I used SMB package for the diode STTH2R06U.
>   The diode temperature increases very quickly when the design is powered and it becomes very hot before crashing.

SMB Rth-jc is 25C/Watt so you should have no problems IF the diode has adequate heat sinking. BUT fig 11 in datasheet shows Rth-ja of 90 C/W - without any heatsinking you are liable to "have problems" if air access is other than superb.

The datasheet says that 3cm^2 of FR4 PCB copper gives about 60 C/W.

> I cannot measure temperature and there is no heatsink for my SMB package. But here I need a quick course about "Thermal resistance junction to ambient versus copper surface under each lead".

If you burn yourself on it you probably need more heat sink.
It COULD run far hotter than that and be OK but ... .
If you are JUST able to keep touching the case it is at about 55 C.
If a drop of water on it boils or if when you lick your finger and dab at it with the wetted finger it hisses then it's over 100 degrees C.
Even that's **perhaps** OK but also maybe not.
If it DOESN'T ever get hiss test hot it's probably OK.

Below: j=junction, c=case, a=air.
Rth = thermal resistance.
Rth_jc is Rth from junction to case.
Rth_ca = case to air.
With no heatsing Rthja = 90 C/W. ie junction is 90C > air temp with no heatsink.
Rthjc is 25 C/W.
So Rth_ca = Rth_ja - Rth_jc = 90-25 = 65 C/W.
Si if air is 20C and case just sizzles = 100C then
Tj = 100 + 25/65 x (Tc-Ta) = 100 + 31 ~= 130 C.

Tj_allowed is < 175C so IF you can keep the leads below 100C (sizzling hot) the temperature SHOULD be OK. Should.

Answer (score 0):

you will solve a problem with CREE SIC Z-REC c3do060 diode, also will be good to change mosfet add INFINEON cool mos P7 series.

Comment: Yes, i have changed the diode with a SiC., works perfect.